# tab action bar, trying to use text field and listview with custom adapter, not working

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-actionbar

ok, here is the main activity which is suppose to show the 2 tabs.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";
//    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);            }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
        MyFriendsListFragment simpleListFragment = new MyFriendsListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, simpleListFragment).commit();
    } 
    else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
        MyFriendsListFragment simpleListFragment = new MyFriendsListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, simpleListFragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;

    }
}
```

}

and here is the class thats being called when one of the tabs is being pressed, right now both tabs are supposed to show the same thing, because both of them call the same class.

```
*public class MyFriendsListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
private ListView lv;
private EditText inputSearch;

public MyFriendsListFragment() {
    Student andres = new Student();
    andres.setFirstName("Andres");
    andres.setLastName("Blanco");

    Student ondria = new Student();
    ondria.setFirstName("Ondria");
    ondria.setLastName("Arias");

    studentList.add(andres);
    studentList.add(ondria);
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> implements Filterable{
    private final Context context;
    public ArrayList<Student> displayValues;
    public ArrayList<Student> originalValues;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Student> values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.displayValues = values;
        this.originalValues = (ArrayList<Student>) values.clone();
    }
    public int getCount(){
         return this.displayValues.size();
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //----This method sets each row of the list individually----            
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);

        if(displayValues.size() > 0)
        {
            Student student = displayValues.get(position);                                
 //Fill Name
                        TextView name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
                        name.setText(student.getFirstName() +  student.getLastName());

        }           
        return itemView;

    }
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter contactFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
             FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();   
             ArrayList<Student> filteredList = new ArrayList<Student>();

             //Filter the list
             if(constraint != null && originalValues !=null) {

                 if(!constraint.toString().isEmpty())
                 {  
                     String constraintLowerCase = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                        for(Student c: originalValues)
                        {                           
                            String cName = c.getFirstName().toLowerCase() ;
                            String cLName = c.getLastName().toLowerCase();
                            if(cName.startsWith(constraintLowerCase) || cLName.startsWith(constraintLowerCase)) 
                            {
                                //Add the row to the list if filtered items
                                filteredList.add(c);
                            }
                        }                                            

                 }

               //Important steps to store the filtered list
                filterResults.values = filteredList;
                filterResults.count = filteredList.size();
              }
              return filterResults;
          }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          @Override
          protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {                                                                                              
              if (results.count > 0) 
              {         
                //Display the filtered list
            MyListAdapter.this.displayValues = (ArrayList<Student>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
              }
              else
              {
                  if(inputSearch.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                  {                 
                    //Display the original list
                      MyListAdapter.this.displayValues = (ArrayList<Student>) MyListAdapter.this.originalValues.clone();
                  }
                  else
                  {                     
                    //Display an empty list
                      MyListAdapter.this.displayValues.clear();
                  }                 
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
              }
          }
         };
        return contactFilter;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);

    try{

    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_view, studentList);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error!!!!!", "00");
    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int pos, long id) {

    try{
    Student clickedStudent = studentList.get(pos);
    int position = pos;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowStudentActivity.class);
    Log.e("CINTENT","CREATED!!!");
    intent.putExtra("clickedContact",clickedStudent);
    intent.putExtra("officialList",studentList);
    intent.putExtra("position",position);
    Log.e("putExtra","Passed"); 
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.e("Start activity","passed");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Catch!","CATCH!!!!");
    }
}
```

}*

When i run it it just crashes and gives me an error saying that there needs to be something inside the listview, but i think i am filling the listview in the oncreateview method. please help me, been at this for a week searching online and have not found any solution, thx!